# what is the right regex for this?

Tags: python, regex, replace

what is the regex for such a task? -->
replace "[[...:" with "[["

That is to say, I want to replace *some text * inside [[...: with [[.

The problem with my code is that it remove *text * inside the first [[ ]]

```
>>> string = "Some text here [[dont remove me]] and some extra text [[remove me:and let this]] here."
>>> clean = re.sub(r'\[\[.+:', '[[', string)
>>> clean
'Some text here [[and let this]] here.'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'\[\[[^:\]]+:', '[[', string)
```

`[^:\]]` is used instead of `.` to constrain that the stuff to remove is limited within a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.` use an expression that excludes `:` and the closing `]]`:

```
r'\[\[(?:[^:\]]|\][^\]])*:'
```